# MySql C# copy data from one table to a second

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

hello i am making a tool that allows people to have an account and a profile picture.

that is all working fine. but i am currently working on adding a friends system in to it.

so at the moment i have a listbox to display all the current users in, for the user who wants to add lets say bob as a friend he would click bobs username in the list box then click the button that says add friend.

a few notes the profile picture needs to be copied as well. which  is  stored as a blob on the database

i currently have this code in to place in the add friend button click

```
 string Query = "INSERT INTO  `tesyt`.`testfriends` SELECT* FROM  `natotool`.`users`.`Username`, `users`.`PIC`";
        MySqlCommand cmd4 = new MySqlCommand(Query, Connection);
        try
        {

            LoginReader = cmd4.ExecuteReader();
            XtraMessageBox.Show("friend added!");

            LoginReader.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            XtraMessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

i know this code will not add the selected username from the listbox as thats what i am needing some help and guidance on. so if anyone can help me out with this by showing be where i should place the listbox1 in the query that would be great as it needs to copy the selected username and the picture that belongs to that username.

a note as well. each user that makes an account will have a new table named after their username where their friends list(username, picture, last time they was on) will be stored.

Thank you all in advance.
Ben

Answer (score 0):

Your query is wrong,`insertion` and `selection` at the time is not allowed in this way. Though you are not working within a stored procedure make two separate calls . You can make it simple this way. First call to get the data from whatever table you want to get and within second call, insert that data within your `testfriend` or any table of your wish.

Another approach is to use `stored procedure`, just pass what to what to insert parameters and do the same thing within a `stored procedure` instead here.

**Note: I don't know how you've designed your DB, make it work like I mentioned. It will hopefully solve your problem.**